# Which version of Ubuntu does my system supports?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, system

I am using laptop having system specification of 4 GB RAM, Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @1.70GHz  1.70GHz. Which version of Ubuntu does my system supports? And does it supports Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: does it supports Ubuntu 22.04 -- Yes

Comment: I'm using a core2 era device which pre-dates the intel *i-series* CPUs and am currently using *kinetic* or what will be Ubuntu 22.10 on release.. All Ubuntu and *flavors* will run on the device, but some may perform better than others for what you intend using the device for (*just as it does on this much older machine I'm currently using*) but hardware is only part of which is best for whatever you intend of the machine..  FYI: I'm not using GNOME currently as *my tastes* & a *lighter* desktop better on this 2009 box.. but I do have GNOME (`ubuntu-desktop`) installed & use it on occasion..

Answer (score 2):

With 4 GB of RAM I would choose Lubuntu. Lightweight DE, and lightweight programs so your OS does not require a tonload of RAM. You can use Youtube and look for reviews of lightweight Linux distributions. Try them before installing and see if all your hardware works.